# Animated re configurable gallery (html/css)

Tags: html, css, gallery, animated

I'm looking to create an html/css gallery with no spacing inbetween each gallery element. Just for some context, all the gallery elements are the same size and are list items contained in a ul inside a div. I already have media queries set up to readjust the rest of the site and the gallery image sizes. However the actual elements are inline-block so they adjust themselves. I want to know how I can make the elements so they animate to their new positions instead of just snapping to them. Adding the standard transition values to the css of any gallery related item didn't seem to work. I'm not sure if I need to change my markup for this to work but any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Animation can not be achieved with css alone. You will need some javascript. I would advise you to have a look at jquery.